# Como faço para deixar uma lista com vários índices se transformar em uma lista com apenas um índice em Python

Tags: python, string, lista

Como faço para transformar um elemento como esse:

```
lista = [testando, este, aplicativo]
```

em uma lista como esta:

```
 lista = [testando este aplicativo]
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso, e se é possível fazer isso com a linguagem Python??

Comment: se for uma lista de `string` você pode usar o método `join()` pra concatenar em uma única `string`

Comment: Era isso mesmo que estava precisando, valeu!

Comment: Coloque as listas dentro de dicionários.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a solução da camillaBim:

```
lista = ["testando", "este", "aplicativo"]
texto = (' ').join(lista)
print(texto)
```